# Не понимаю работу цикла в python

Tags: python, циклы, python-2.x

Здравствуйте!

```
a = [(['192.168.0.1'], ['8080']), (['192.168.0.2'], ['4662']), (['192.168.0.3'], ['8080', '4662']), (['192.168.0.4'], ['8080', '4662']), (['192.168.0.5'], ['8080', '4662']), (['192.168.0.6'], ['8080']), (['192.168.0.8'], ['80', '443'])]
```

Почему вот так работает: `for key,val in a: d[key[0]] = val`

А вот так не работает: `[(d[key[0]] = val) for key,val in a]`

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [(d[key[0]] = val) for key,val in a]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Может как-то это можно записать короче/красивше?

И почему `[a.remove(item) for item in a if '8080' in item[1]]` удаляет не все значения за раз? То есть надо несколько раз выполнить выражение, чтоб удалить все совпадения.

**И ещё самый важный вопрос**: Подскажите пожалуйста самый правильный метод работы с данными в python типа key:value (как в примере выше, но очень много), чтоб потом можно было производить поиск как по key, так и по value и найденную пару удалять? В данный момент у меня лист туплов с листами (как в примере выше), но оно мне по виду не нравится :) и я решил перевести это всё в словарь, но как пишут в интернетах - словари для этого не предназначены.

Answer (score 1):

Использование списочного выражение `[val for val in key]` подразумевает получение значения в список. Выражение `(d[key[0]] = val)` ничего не возвращает и потому в список ничего не уходит. Отсюда и ошибка, все равно что написать `print (a = 1)`.

Помимо этого не понятно, что вы хотите получить. Ведь для получения значений достаточно написать просто `val`, а для получения ключей есть функция `keys()`. В любом случае не стоит зацикливаться на том, что бы код всегда был короче, это одна из ошибок кодирования. Лучше пускай он будет понятнее и быстрее, но не короче.

---

Если вы удаляете значение из коллекции, то его внутренний счетчик перестраивается и вы получаете неверное значение. Ну для примера:

```
a = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
for val in a:
    if val == "three":
        a.remove(val)
    print(val)
```

Как только цикл получит третий элемент, он его удалит и четвертый станет на место третьего. Теперь их там три. Но цикл об этом ничего не знает не будет еще раз получать новый третий элемент, он его пропустит и попытается получить четвертый, которого уже не существует.

Так же и тут, перестройка счетчика не дает Вам получить корректный результат в цикле. Поэтому получайте ссылки и потом удаляйте уже отдельно элементы.

---

Для больших объемов данных типа key-value мне на ум приходят только БД, но не знаю как они относятся к вашей задаче. Поэтому в данном вопросе ничем не помогу.

Comment: Спасибо, я не совсем правильно выразился. Мне не нужно долгосрочно хранить key:value, мне нужно хранить это в памяти пока работает скрипт. То есть мне надо как-то с этим работать: Правильно, удобно, быстро. Вот я и ищу как. А можно пример как удалять по ссылкам? Ну и раз уж мы так душевно беседуем, возможно Вы подскажите почему не работает это: http://pastebin.com/eDb4Afp3 :)

Answer (score 0):

По поводу вопроса, который вы задали в комментарии к ответу от Alex Krass.

Если я правильно понял, вам нужен фильтр, который будет проверять, что хотя бы один номер порта из шаблона содержится в номерах порта в элементах основного списка.

В этом случае, вам нужно вот это:

```
fl = ['8080', '4662']
a = [(['192.168.0.1'], ['8080']), (['192.168.0.2'], ['4662']), (['192.168.0.3'], ['8080', '4662']), (['192.168.0.4'], ['8080', '4662']), (['192.168.0.5'], ['8080', '4662']), (['192.168.0.6'], ['8080']), (['192.168.0.8'], ['80', '443'])]

result = filter(lambda x: (any([f in x[1] for f in fl])), a)

print(list(result))
```